# Android: Overwrite standard xml layout's properties for list item

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way of using the standard android xml files (simple list item multiple choices) and only adjust some of the properties so that I can also use the standard adapters? For now I made a new view xml and copied the code from simple_list_item_multiple_choice. There I only added a background color. This works, but now I have the almost same code 2 times.

I also know that custom view and custom adapter would work, but I hope there is a more "smart" solution for this (in my case really only the background color matters, the rest is fine). It seems a lot more code for only changing the background color of an item.

I thought with include/merge tags I could include the standard xml and justify to my needs, but this doesnt work (also because I couldn't use the standard arrayAdapter anymore)

This is how my view looks now:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out? [Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

I am not sure if this is what your question meant but according to what I could grasp, you were talking of styles only

Comment: yes, I looked into styles. But as I understood I have to define which style to use in a views xml. As I want to use a standard android view, I would have to set the style there (what is not really possible). That is also the reason I copied the code and added the background there. Programmatically styling is not possible afaik. So I guess this won't bring me further